# Dell PowerEdge 850 CPU upgrade to Pentium 4 E5400 not working

Tags: cpu, upgrade, dell-poweredge

I bought a new [dual-core Pentium 4 CPU (E5400)](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=40478) for my PowerEdge 850 (800Mhz FSB), and it's not even going through the POST. What am I missing? I updated the BIOS to the latest version (A04), and no luck.

```
   http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/850_specs.pdf
```

Comment: The E5400 is not considered a Pentium D processor..http://ark.intel.com/ProductCollection.aspx?familyID=41877&MarketSegment=DT

Comment: My understanding is the core2 processors requires a special voltage regulatior on the motherboard, since Pentium D processors did not need this it will not be present on the motherboard, so no you cannot update to any core2 processor, you are stuck with Pentium Dual cores. I bios update will not solve it either, its a hardware issue.

Answer (score 2):

The Pentium you bought is one of the new(ish) ones derived from the Core 2 line.

Just because it physically fits in the machine does not mean it is compatible. Sometimes you can get lucky and other times like now - unfortunately you are not lucky!

If it isn't working with the latest BIOS update, it means that it is not compatible - you can live in hope that they release an update in the future, but it is unlikely to find a machine/chipset that is compatible both with Pentium 4s and Core 2 era of CPUs